# Image Resizer usage in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, image-resizing, imageresizer

I made a NuGet installation to use ImageResizer API's. But whatever I do, It didn't get start..

1)I made NuGet installation
2)in my .aspx web page I put .ashx?width=30px&height=15px at the end of my picture.

aaaaaand it's gone.
But in web.config file it says:

```
<!-- Unless you (a) use Integrated mode, or (b) map all reqeusts to ASP.NET, 
         you'll need to add .ashx to your image URLs: image.jpg.ashx?width=200&height=20 -->
```

I am confused.. If I need to do something else before using it, Where are the instructions??

Thank you..

The problem was because of installation of wrong NuGet packages.

> "You need to install ImageResizer.MvcWebConfig per our installation
>   instructions: http://imageresizing.net/docs/install"

If you install NuGet packages per instructions in that page, You'll easily be able to begin using ImageResizer tool.. And also you have to use numeric paramaters, not string. As stated below.

Thank you again, Nathanael Jones.

Comment: Is your application in integrated mode or is it running in classic?

Comment: It runs in integerated mode.. I changed it to classic right after you told it. But it is still the same.. Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Width and Height values are numeric, not strings.

Use `width=30&height=15`, not `?width=30px&height=15px`